# What is a multilevel database?

Tags: database

I've come across the "multilevel database" term whilst reading a textbook but it did not provide a proper definition with regards to what it is. Google didn't help either. Can anyone help define this concept to me and how it defers from a standard database implementaion?

Comment: Hmm, unusual. Perhaps you could provide a short quote for context?

Comment: Google has lots of results: http://www.google.com/search?q=multilevel+databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://books.google.com/books?id=O3VB-zspJo4C&lpg=PA343&ots=pP1xPnuB_C&dq=multilevel%20databases&pg=PA323) to pages that describe multilevel databases from **Security in Computing** By Shari Lawrence Pfleeger at Google Books.

Briefly, a multilevel database provides granular security for data depending on the sensitivity of the data field and clearance of the user for both writing and reading data.

Comment: Anyone know of a commercial db product that supports this?

Answer (score 0):

A multilevel database as far as I understand it is a Column based table with different security and view layers. I found this which kinda confirms my thoughts.

> The first layer corresponds to a model
>   for a non-protected database. The
>   second layer corresponds to a model
>   for a multilevel database. In this
>   second layer, we propose a list of
>   theorems that must be respected in
>   order to build a secure multilevel
>   database. We also propose a new
>   solution to manage cover stories
>   without using the ambiguous technique
>   of polyinstantiation. The third layer
>   corresponds to a model for a MultiView
>   database, that is, a database that
>   provides at each security level a
>   consistent view of the multilevel
>   database.

Comment: Would you care to give a source for your quote?

Comment: Googling gives the abstract for [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X98000445), but it would be good for OP to cite it.